# Rewrite slug выдает ошибку 404

Tags: wordpress

Суть такая: нужно получить ссылки на кастомные записи вида: 
**сайт/выбранный_термин_таксономии_type/название_поста.** 
Обновляю постоянные ссылки, но все равно на страницах записей выдает 404 ошибку. Что делаю не так или как правильно сделать как хочу?
1.регистрирую кастомную таксономию

```
 register_taxonomy('type_cases',array('cases'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => false,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => false,
));
```

2. регистрирую кастомный тип записи

```
$args = [
        'labels' => [
            'name' => 'Кейсы',
            'singular_name' => 'Кейс',
            'add_new' => 'Добавить новый кейс',
            'search_items' => 'Поиск кейсов',
            'not_found' => 'Кейсов не было найдено',
        ],
        'description' => 'Кейсы',
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-gallery',
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'  => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug'=>'%typesq%', 'with_front'=>false, 'pages'=>false, 'feeds'=>false, 'feed'=>false ),
        //'rewrite'            => true,
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => false,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => 5,
        'supports'           => array('title'),
        'taxonomies'         => array( 'type_cases' ),
    ];
    register_post_type( 'cases', $args );
```

3. Применяю правило замены slug

```
    add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'types_permalink', 1, 2 );
function types_permalink( $permalink, $post ){

    // выходим если это не наш тип записи: без холдера %types%
    if( strpos( $permalink, '%typesq%' ) === false )
        return $permalink;

    // Получаем элементы таксы
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'type_cases' );
    // если есть элемент заменим холдер
    if( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && !empty( $terms ) && is_object( $terms[0] ) )
        $term_slug = array_pop( $terms )->slug;
    // элемента нет, а должен быть...
    else
        $term_slug = 'no-type';

    return str_replace( '%typesq%', $term_slug, $permalink );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось очень не простым, я знал в какую сторону копать, но понятия не имел как правильно это сделать. При замене slug нужно научить WP понимать новые ссылки (перезаписанные), они пытаются обратиться к post_type attachment, поэтому создаем такую функцию, которая изменяет запрос изнутри:

```
add_filter('request', 'rudr_post_type_request', 1, 1 );

function rudr_post_type_request( $query ){
    global $wpdb;

    $post_type_name = 'cases'; // specify your own here
    $tax_name = 'type_cases'; // and here

    $slug = $query['attachment']; // when we change the post type link, WordPress thinks that these are attachment pages

    // get the post with the given type and slug from the database
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_var(
        "
        SELECT ID
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_name = '$slug'
        AND post_type = '$post_type_name'
        "
    );

    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $tax_name ); // our post should have the terms


    if( isset( $slug ) && $post_id && !is_wp_error( $terms ) && !empty( $terms ) ) : // change the query

        unset( $query['attachment'] );
        $query[$post_type_name] = $slug;
        $query['post_type'] = $post_type_name;
        $query['name'] = $slug;

    endif;

    return $query;
}
```